# <ol> Ordering everything as the number 1 when reading a text file in PHP

Tags: php

I am reading a textfile using PHP and the data is being outputted. The issue I am having is with the formatting of the ol and li tags. The baseball players I am outputting all are numbered as number "1." how do I get the numbers to order chronologically?

HTML/PHP

```
<?php

$filename ='../teammembers.txt';

$readLines = count(file($filename));
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');

for($i = 1; $i <= $readLines ; $i++)
{
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $teammembers = trim($line);
    print '<ol><li>Team Member: ' . $teammembers. '</li></ol>';
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: could you provide a sample of teammembers.txt

Comment: You're printing a complete list every time in your loop. `<ol><li></li></ol><ol><li></li></ol><ol><li></li></ol>...`

Comment: You do realise that when you call `file($filename)` it will return an array of all of the lines in the file.  You don't need to read the file again in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're builing a complete list every time inside your loop. Move the `<ol>` and `</ol>` outside the loop and only output the list items:

```
echo "<ol>";
for($i = 1; $i <= $readLines ; $i++)
{
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $teammembers = trim($line);
    print '<li>Team Member: ' . $teammembers. '</li></ol>';
}
echo "</ol>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new list for every item:

```
<ol><li>Team Member: Mike</li></ol>
<ol><li>Team Member: Frank</li></ol>
<ol><li>Team Member: Henry</li></ol>
```

What you want is a single list with just a new element for each item:

```
<ol>
    <li>Team Member: Mike</li>
    <li>Team Member: Frank</li>
    <li>Team Member: Henry</li>
</ol>
```

Move the `<ol>` and `</ol>` parts outside of your loop:

```
print '<ol>';
for($i = 1; $i <= $readLines ; $i++)
{
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $teammembers = trim($line);
    print '<li>Team Member: ' . $teammembers. '</li>';
}
print '</ol>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `ol` outside.

```
$filename ='../teammembers.txt';

$readLines = count(file($filename));
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');

print '<ol>';
for($i = 1; $i <= $readLines ; $i++)
{
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $teammembers = trim($line);
    print '<li>Team Member: ' . $teammembers. '</li>';
}
print '</ol>';

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the above comment, calling [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) will read all of the file into an array for you, so you already have all of the lines loaded and then in the loop, you read the file again.

So once you've called file (I use the options as you don't need the line feed at the end of the line).  It then trims all of the lines and then uses `implode()` to build up the list...

```
$readLines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$readLines = array_map('trim', $readLines);
echo '<ol><li>Team Member: '.
        implode("</li><li>Team Member: ", $readLines).
        '</li></ol>';
```

So with a file...

```
Mike 
 Frank
 Henry
```

outputs...

```
<ol><li>Team Member: Mike</li><li>Team Member: Frank</li><li>Team Member: Henry</li></ol>
```